# How to setup Virtual Host on XAMPP?

Tags: apache, xampp, vhosts

I'm using xampp v7.2.29.

But I can't setup a Virtual Host(vHost).
Here is my code:

**apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs"
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.demoapp.com
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\DemoApp"
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\DemoApp">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host**

```
127.0.0.1       locl.demoapp.com
```

I'm using the above code but getting this error.

[Click to s see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG0IX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo error on your host file.

Since you used

```
local.demoapp.com
```

as your server name, your host file should be

```
127.0.0.1    local.demoapp.com
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also follow this.

Input the configuration bellow : make sure to change your file location to DocumentRoot, Directory and change ServerName.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Volumes/Storage/niamrox.dev/web/practice/batch_1_project"
ServerName habizabi.com
<Directory "/Volumes/Storage/niamrox.dev/web/practice/batch_1_project">
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

After that restart your Apache Server by Xampp service.

Find your own pc IP address.

Then find and open host file. If you are windown user edit

```
C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

If you are OSX / Mc user then open terminal and and copy paste the following code below ‘sudo nano /private/etc/hosts’

at host file write your ip address and server name like bellow

```
192.168.1.2 habizabi.com
```

After that restart your apache server and browse the server name on browser. You will find the project there.

You can [follow this tutorial](https://niamrox.com/create-virtual-host-on-xampp/) for better understanding